# Why does Log1p to perform log transformation not plot as a normalized histogram?

Tags: r, plot, histogram, logarithm

I am a beginner in R, trying to use log1p to normalize my data which is currently right-skewed. But when I create the normalized histogram, it plots a single solid square block rather than normalized bins. How can I fix this?

```
# Histogram of SalePrice with skewed-right distribution 
ggplot(data=train, aes(train$SalePrice)) + 
  ggtitle("Histogram for Sale Price") + 
  xlab("Sale Price") +
  ylab("Count")+
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 10000)

# We can normalize the data by way of log-transformation
train$SalePrice <- log1p(train$SalePrice)

# Histogram of SalePrice with normal distribution 
ggplot(data=train, aes(train$SalePrice)) + 
  ggtitle("Histogram for Sale Price") + 
  xlab("Sale Price") +
  ylab("Count")+
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 10000)
```

[Right-skewed histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oncjb.png)
[Solid-block "histogram"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARhDy.png)

Comment: It's because `log1p(6e5) = 13.30469` and you set the binwidth to 10000. Hence, all your sale price values are in a single bin. Try running it without specifying the binwidth. Also note: don't use `ggplot(data=train, aes(train$SalePrice))` but `ggplot(data=train, aes(SalePrice))` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much -- got it, makes sense. It works now!

Answer (score 0):

Answer from user docendo discimus: "It's because log1p(6e5) = 13.30469 and you set the binwidth to 10000. Hence, all your sale price values are in a single bin. Try running it without specifying the binwidth. Also note: don't use ggplot(data=train, aes(train$SalePrice)) but ggplot(data=train, aes(SalePrice)) instead. – docendo discimus"